# Returns the length of the longest sequence of identical digits found in num recursive

Tags: java, recursion

I had an assignement;

"Write a recursive static method that accepts a positive integer num and returns the length of the longest sequence of identical digits found in num."

This is the solution I did

```
public static int equalDigits (int num)
{
    return equalDigits(num,1,0);
}

private static int equalDigits (int num, int count, int max){ 
    if (num < 10)
        return 1;
    if (num/10%10 == num%10)
        count++;
    else
        count = 1;
    max = count > max ? count : max;
    return Math.max(max,equalDigits(num/10,count,max));
}
```

But my lecturer said it can be done without using helper method.
I can't figured how exactly it's possible.

Comment: maybe obvious, but perhaps with the method call being made directly to your helper function, so keeping the three argument function and getting rid of the one argument function

Comment: @KMehta They gave us the method signature which is "public static int equalDigits (int num)"

Comment: This is a poor use case for recursion, but taking the problem at face value, I don't see how you can keep track of the longest run while also passing the current run length through the call stack.

Comment: Well, you can simply create a string out of the number, then check for each character if it is a digit, while keeping a max and a counter. Your method is also fine, and can be performed in a while loop or similar too. Do `x % 10`, check resulting digit value - keeping count & max, then do `x = x / 10` until `x` is zero. Personally I like it when operations are not "stringified".

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code using your methodology, so without using `String` (which I would consider ugly):

```
public static int equalDigits(int num)
{
    // this is a so-called guard statement at the start to disallow invalid arguments
    if (num < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expecting positive value or zero");
    }
    
    int currentDigit = -1; // "magic value" outside of range
    int count = 0;
    int maxCount = 0;
    int x = num; // good practice not to operate on parameters
    while (x > 0) {
        int digit = x % 10;
        if (digit == currentDigit) {
            count++;
        } else {
            // only update max count when needed
            // TODO set maxcount
            // TODO something with digits

            // don't forget the initial digit, so not zero
            // TODO set initial count
        }
        x /= 10; // yes, it exists, is identical to x = x / 10
    }
    // if the last count was higher we still need to adjust
    // TODO set maxcount
    
    return maxCount;
}
```

I've removed the stuff that you need to get it to work, but I've shown how you can do this without recursive operations, as that can be hard to refactor.